# Найти и переместить файлы

Tags: bash

Нужно, чтобы команда искала файлы с расширением .dem, которые были изменены более чем 5 минут назад, и перемещала их. Написал такую строчку, но не работает:

```
find /home/csgo/csgo -type f -name *.dem -cmin +5 -exec mv /home/demos {} \;
```

выдает ошибку типа

> cannot overwrite non-directory

Comment: логично. посмотрите в команду - ` mv /home/demos {}` - Вы пытаетесь переместить папку  /home/demos в все найденные файлы

Comment: а как правильно тогда будет?

Comment: наверное, нужно переставить аргументы местами. Это, как мне кажется, логично (первый аргумент mv  это что перемещаем, а второй - куда)

Comment: уже разобрался, если кому нужно будет
find /home/csgo/csgo -type f -name '*.dem' -cmin +5 -exec mv {} /home/demos \;

так работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

общий синтаксис использования опции `-exec` программы *find*:

```
-exec программа [опции-или-аргументы-программы] \;
```

среди опций или аргументов можно использовать конструкцию `'{}'` (кавычки нужны, чтобы оболочка не приняла эту конструкцию на свой счёт, а передала программе *find* так, как есть). вместо этой конструкции программа *find* будет подставлять каждый удовлетворяющий критериям поиска файл/каталог и выполнять получившуюся команду.

---

общий синтаксис вызова программы *mv*:

```
mv что-копируем куда-копируем
```

когда программа *mv* используется в качестве значения для опции `-exec` программы *find*, то обычно (и в вашем случае так и есть) перемещают то, что найдено программой *find* в указанное место.

т.е., конструкцию `'{}'` надо поставить **первым** аргументом программы *mv*:

```
-exec mv '{}' куда-копируем \;
```

Comment: Можно ещё `-exec mv -t /home/demos {} +`

Comment: @jfs, при написании ответа на элементарный вопрос частенько самое трудное — вовремя остановиться.

Comment: Не могли бы вы более явно выразить вашу мысль? Как она связана с моим комментарием?

Comment: @jfs, когда я пишу ответ на элементарный вопрос, часто приходится ограничивать себя, чтобы не углубляться в детали, нюансы, варианты. чтобы ответ не превращался в простыню, пересказывающую (например) man-ы. возможно, вам стоит написать отдельный ответ, в котором предложить использование опции `-t` программы *mv* (и, может быть, ещё что-нибудь полезное/интересное).

Comment: я не могу понять как это относится к моему комментарию. Если бы я хотел оставить ответ, я бы оставил ответ. Для меня основной характеристикой вопроса/ответа является его полезность. Я не сомневаюсь, что вы прекрасно знакомы  с содержимым комментария. Комментарий не для вас, а для будущих читателей этого вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Борец за использование *xargs* просит внимания.

Идет вместе с find (gnu findutils)  работает быстрей и гибче.

```
~$ find ./ -type f -cmin +5 -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' mv '{}' /home/demos
```

Или даже в три (n) потока!

```
~$ find ./ -type f -cmin +5 -print0 | xargs -0 -P3 -I'{}' mv '{}' /home/demos/
```

Comment: при описании вариаций использования содержимого *stdout* программы *find* можно упомянуть, например, и *gnu/parallel*.

Comment: @aleksandr_batakin просто xargs идет вместе с find у него не сложный синтаксис parallel это своенравный зверь.

Comment: ни в коем случае не пытаясь спорить, выскажу лишь удивление: это что получается, у *gnu/parallel* «сложный синтаксис»? `$ find ... | parallel mv '{}' куда`